# PWA in Angular and Custom Install

Tags: angular, installation, progressive-web-apps

I feel really stupid for asking this, but I'm new to Angular and javascript in general, so I'm at at a loss here. My project runs fine (it's fairly simple) and made all the changes for it to be a PWA (and it is), but there's a thing I can't get my head around.

My problem, is that my app doesn't seem to trigger the `beforeinstallprompt` action. I've run lighthouse and my app is totally installable and pwa ready(https, service worker, manifest, etc), but I can't trace why this event is not being triggered (the console shows nothing).

Actually, the problem is larger, since I cannot for the life of me understand how can I actually built a custom, say, button for installing the pwa. I've read [this](https://web.dev/customize-install/#how-to-provide-your-own-in-app-install-experience) and [this](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/turn-your-angular-app-into-a-pwa-in-4-easy-steps-543510a9b626) and I've seen many times [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWRdBywm4Zo&list=PLNYkxOF6rcIB2xHBZ7opgc2Mv009X87Hh&index=5), apart from a ton of the same, more or less, question in SO, but I can't figure out some basic things. For instance I'm seeing everywhere this snippet that listens for the event and stores it for later use:

```
let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  // Prevent the mini-infobar from appearing on mobile
  e.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
  // Update UI notify the user they can install the PWA
  showInstallPromotion();
});
```

or this, which triggers the custom installation proccess:

```
buttonInstall.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 // Hide the app provided install promotion
  hideMyInstallPromotion();
  // Show the install prompt
  deferredPrompt.prompt();
  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
  deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
    if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
      console.log('User accepted the install prompt');
    } else {
      console.log('User dismissed the install prompt');
    }
  });
});
```

but the thing is I don't know if it's supposed to go in the template file (e.g. example.component.html), the ts file (e.g. example.component.ts), the root ts file (e.g. app.component.ts) or do I need to make a service or something entirely different. Someone might -very correctly- say, go on and do your homework, but the point is that I can't seem to find the right resource or I'm that stupid (chances are, that the latter applies).

So, my real question is, can someone point out with as much detail possible where should my code reside, because angular is very pretty and  tidy, but I'm stupid?

Thanks for taking time reading this, really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you testing the Install on HTTPS?

Comment: Have you totally cleared out your cache from previous testing/installs?

Comment: Yeap, I've tried different browsers, both in normal and incognito mode, cleared the cache, the whole lot. But no matter what I do, `beforeinstallprompt` doesn't seem to be fired.

Comment: Here is a simple example I created that shows an install button. It's a couple of years old, but the code is still close I think. https://a2hs.glitch.me/

Comment: Source for above here https://github.com/ng-chicago/AddToHomeScreen